# How to include system variable in batch file inside FOR loop ? also escaping the ! and % sign inside variable?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

lets say i have a list file contains folder names that i want to delete periodically based on a list,

currently using this batch file which don't work as i expected :

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F "tokens=2* delims==" %%x in ('findstr/brc:"foldertodelete" garbagefolderlist.txt') do (
    set "foldertodelete=%%x"
    set foldertodelete=!foldertodelete:"=!
    set foldertodelete=!foldertodelete:%%=^!!"
    echo !foldertodelete!
    if exist !foldertodelete! (
        echo deleting !foldertodelete!
        rmdir /s /q !foldertodelete!>nul
        )
    )
endlocal
```

inside garbagefolderlist.txt :

```
foldertodelete="%programfiles%\blablabla"
fodlertodelete=%systemroot%\blablabla
foldertodelete="C:\Temp"
foldertodelete=D:\Temporary files\here
```

**notes about the list file (garbagefolderlist.txt) :**

1. folder names may contains **double quotes or not**, so i want to dynamically eliminate the double quotes inside batch file

2. folder names may be plain or using **system variable or not** like %systemroot%, etc

3. folder names may contains spaces

Comment: If all you have is a hammer, may the escape-force be with you...

Comment: Start by opening up a command prompt and reading the help file for the `FOR` command. Especially the very last section about the command modifiers. `FOR /?`. That will save you one headache.

Comment: You should only enable delayed expansion when you need it.  So enable it after you have assigned the for variable to the environmental variable then use the endlocal as the last line executed in your `FOR` command.  I am not totally understanding why you are changing percent symbols to exclamation points.

Comment: @Squashman would you mind to just write me a sample that works ? been trying to figure out about 4 hours but still no luck lol

Comment: I can't because I can't understand your question or your logic as to what you are trying to do. Why are you trying to change percent symbols to exclamation points?

Comment: @Squashman my purpose changing the percent sign is to make the system variable (%programfiles%) works or translated to !programfiles!, as from what i read a variable must use exclamation instead of percent in delayedexpansion enabled

Comment: You can't do double delayed variable expansion.

Comment: the list (.txt) file may contains prefixes like **foldertodelete** , **filetodelete** , **foldertomake** , **filetomake** , **registrytoimport** , etc with (=) delimiter, so i want the batch file (.bat) to smartly populate each list prefixes into each command by eliminating the double quotes (if exist), pointing system variables to correct locations (%programfiles% to C:\Program Files\), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is delete the folders listed in that text file you only need one single line of code.  You need to use the `CALL` command to get the double variable expansion that you require. You don't even need delayed expansion at all.

```
for /F "tokens=2* delims==" %%x in ('findstr /bc:"foldertodelete" garbagefolderlist.txt') do call rmdir /s /q "%%~x" 2>nul
```

Here is the execution of your script on my system.  I created a folder in Program Files and I also have a Temp folder on the C: drive. The line in your file with %systemroot% will not be chosen because you have a typo on that line.  So the script will only attempt to process three lines from your input example.

I have added the echo to the code and removed the error dump to nul so that you can see all the output.

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=2* delims==" %%x in ('findstr /bc:"foldertodelete" garbagefolderlist.txt') do (
    call echo %%~x
    call rmdir /s /q "%%~x"
)
```

And here is the output of that code.

```
C:\BatchFiles\SO\71120676>so.bat
C:\Program Files\blablabla
Access is denied.
C:\Temp
D:\Temporary files\here
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

So lets break down that output.

1. You can see that the %programfiles% variable is expanded as it echo's the folder name correctly but the folder cannot be deleted because I am not running from an elevated cmd prompt as Administrator.  So that folder cannot be deleted.
2. The temp folder displays correctly and is deleted.
3. The last directory does not exist on my system as I don't have a D: drive so the system reports that it cannot find the path. If standard error was still being redirected to the NUL device you would not see the error which is why I don't bother with checking if a folder exists before I delete it.

Comment: I want the system variable expanded too, while displaying the result or the folder that will be deleted, i tried with what you write (replacing rmdir* with echo) but system variable isn't expanded, (%programfiles% still echoed as %programfiles%, not "C:\Program Files")

Comment: @AndreB `CALL echo %%~x` will most CERTAINLY expand the lines with variables to the value of their system variable names.  Feel free to prove me wrong.  I have tested this. I don't post answers unless I have tested them.

Comment: just tested with "call" and it works, but i want a print only if the directory exist